# Form validation submission and First letter capitalized in output of submission of Name and City

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, form-submit

Hello all this is the last call for for help with the my form validation submission. When I fail a validation the form still submits. I need to know how to stop the form from submitting if I even fail even one validation.

I need to print out the “Name” and “City” fields in the following format on submission if possible.

```
                           Name: Namestring
                           City: Citystring
```

In the strings of the “Name” and “City” must begin with an upper case letter followed by all lower case letters.

For example, if a user types “peTer. ” in the name box, and “Philadelphia” in the city box, the output message should display them as: Peter or City. The first letter must always be a capital via output on submission. Basically no matter how I typed in the name and city field in the output the first letter is upper case and the remaining letter is lower case.

```
function doClear()
{
    document.PizzaForm.customer.value ="";
    document.PizzaForm.address.value = "";
    document.PizzaForm.city.value = "";
    document.PizzaForm.state.value="PA";
    document.PizzaForm.zip.value="";
    document.PizzaForm.phone.value="";
    document.PizzaForm.email.value="";


    document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked = false;

    document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked = false;
    document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked = false;

    return;
}

function validateMe() {

   if ( !(validateText() && validateRadio() && validateTops()) ) {
      return false;
   }

    var toppings = ""
    for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++){
        if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
            toppings += (i==0?"":",")+document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
    }

    alert("Name:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.customer.value + 
          '\n' + 
          "Address:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.address.value + 
          '\n' +
          "City:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.city.value +
          '\n' +
          "State:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.state.value +
          '\n' +
          "Zip:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.zip.value +
          '\n' +
          "Phone:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.phone.value +
          '\n' +
          "Email:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.email.value +
          '\n' +
          "Size:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.sizes.value +
          '\n' +
          "Toppings:" + " " + toppings);
    return;
}
function validateText()
{
    var customer = document.PizzaForm.customer.value;
    if (customer.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter your name.")
    }
    var address = document.PizzaForm.address.value;
    if (address.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter your address.")
    }
    var city = document.PizzaForm.city.value;
    if (city.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter your city.")
    }
    var state = document.PizzaForm.state.value;
    if (state.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter your state.")
    }
    var zip = document.PizzaForm.zip.value;
    if (document.PizzaForm.zip.value == "" ||
    isNaN( document.PizzaForm.zip.value ) ||
    document.PizzaForm.zip.value.length != 5 )
    {
        alert("Please enter the required zip code format.")
    }

    var phone = document.PizzaForm.phone.value;
    if (!/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/.test(document.PizzaForm.phone.value)) {
    alert("Please enter the correct phone format xxx-xxx-xxxxx.");

    }

    var email = document.PizzaForm.email.value;
        atpos = email.indexOf("@");
        dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || ( dotpos - atpos < 2 ))
    {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.")
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}


function validateRadio()
{
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[0].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[1].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[2].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes[3].checked) return true;
    if (document.PizzaForm.sizes.value == false);
    {
        alert("Please select a pizza size.");
    }
    return;
}

function validateTops()
{
    if (document.PizzaForm.toppings[0].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[1].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[2].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[3].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[4].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[5].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[6].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[7].checked == false &&
        document.PizzaForm.toppings[8].checked == false)
        {
            alert("Please select a topping of your choice.");
        }
            return false;
            return true;
}


</script> 
</head>
<body>

<form name="PizzaForm"   onsubmit="return validateMe()">
<h1>The JavaScript Pizza Parlor</h1>
<p>
<h4>Step 1: Enter your Name, Address, City, State Phone number, and Email:</h4>
<font face ="Courier New">
Name: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="customer" size="50" type="text"><br>
Address:&nbsp;<Input name="address" size="50" type="text"><br>
City:  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="city" size="15"type="text">
State:<select name="state"> 
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="PA">PA</option>
      <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
      <option value="NY">NY</option>
      <option value="DE">DE</option>
      </select>
Zip:<Input name="zip" size="7"type="text"><br>
Phone: &nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="phone" size="50"type="text"><br>
Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;<Input name="email" size="31"type="text"><br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 2: Select the size of pizza you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Small">Small
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Medium">Medium
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Large">Large
<input name="sizes" type="radio" value="Jumbo">Jumbo<br>
</font>
</p>
<p>
<h4>Step 3: Select the pizza toppings you want:</h4>
<font face="Courier New">
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Canadian Bacon">Canadian Bacon
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Sausage">Sausage<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms">Mushrooms
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Pineapple">Pineapple
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Black Olives">Black Olives<br>
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Green Peppers">Green Peppers
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Extra Cheese">Extra Cheese
<input name="toppings" type="checkbox" value="Plain">Plain<br>
</font>
</p>
<!--
========================================================
The submit and clear form buttons below.
========================================================
-->
<input type="button" value="Submit Order" onClick="Submit Order">
<input type="button" value="Clear Entries" onClick="doClear()">

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

I need the smallest code that will be able to accomplish my requirements. Java script only and not JQuery as I have no experiences in that area.

Thank you All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize the onsubmit attribute of the form.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateMe()">
   <!-- whatever fields go here -->
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function validateMe() {
   // Return false if invalid input.
   if ( !(validateText() && validateRadio() && validateTops()) ) {
      return false;
   }

   // Otherwise, we're planning on submitting the form.
   // Alert a confirmation and return true.

   var toppings = "";
   for(i=0;i<document.PizzaForm.toppings.length;i++){
     if(document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].checked)
        toppings += (i==0?"":",")+document.PizzaForm.toppings[i].value;
   }

   alert("Name:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.customer.value + 
      '\n' + 
      "Address:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.address.value + 
      '\n' +
      "City:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.city.value +
      '\n' +
      "State:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.state.value +
      '\n' +
      "Zip:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.zip.value +
      '\n' +
      "Phone:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.phone.value +
      '\n' +
      "Email:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.email.value +
      '\n' +
      "Size:" + " " + document.PizzaForm.sizes.value +
      '\n' +
      "Toppings:" + " " + toppings);

   return true;
}
```

Change your "Submit Order" button to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Order">
```

And you can remove the doSubmit function altogether.

To upper case first letter of string:

```
function capitalizeString(stringToCapitalize) {
    var words = stringToCapitalize.split(' ');
    for (var i=0, il=words.length; i<il; i++) {
        if (words[i].length > 0) {
            words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase()
                       + words[i].substring(1, words[i].length);
        }
    }
    return words.join(' ');
}
```

In your case for city:

```
alert("City: " + capitalizeString(document.PizzaForm.city.value));
```

Comment: Where do I place and or place the function validateMe(). I ask because when I put it in my form it does not even submit. I tried placing it at the bottom of the script and in the brackets I typed the name of the form but nothing works.

Comment: You can put it anywhere inline with the other functions you have defined. The function needs to return true if the form input is valid, false otherwise. I'll update answer.

Comment: I guess my issue is my experience with programing. I really don't know the logic that checks if invalid. Basically what to put in the brackets.

Comment: You're already kind of doing it. Those functions called validateText, validateRadio, validateTops are all returning true or false depending on whether or not valid input was given. The point is, whatever function you use in the onsubmit, if it returns false the form won't submit.

Comment: Code seems good as I get alerts if I select nothing or enter nothing but once I enter all the information and selections, the form does not submit when I hit the submit button and there is no output of selections and completed text field. What is causing this?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Nothing happens at all.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to reflect what you currently have?

Comment: You didn't change the "Submit Order" button to <input type="submit"> also remove the onclick.

Comment: Thanks the submit buttons works now but the form only stops after validateText().  Nothing els gets validated. Thanks for all you help.

Comment: This has been corrected and all is good . Now all I need is to have a the Name and city converts the first letter to uppercase in the alert out put after submission

Comment: Yesssssssssss  Yessssssssssss thank you. You are the man OMGGGGGGGGG.